# Load bearing wall removed from house that I bought now it’s sagging

Tags: building

This was a load bearing wall and the people I bought it off of moved it now it’s sagging I don’t want to put a beam in the middle of my room what can I do

Sagging beam [image]

Comment: Load bearing walls or beams with posts are what hold up a house.  Without them the house will collapse(in time).  It will need replacing, but a structural engineer should be able to design something that looks nice.  If another floor is on top, instead of just an attic, this becomes a job to get started on now.  If just an attic, can maybe wait a couple of days.

Comment: I am guessing the picture is sideways. The red beam appears to the dropping below the ceiling as if it is a fake beam. If a structural beam sags, the ceiling comes down with it, not letting a gap be created. Definitely worth having a pro look at. If the other side has dropped with the beam, as in there is no gap, one side is bearing the picture side is not.

Comment: Maybe the red beam was installed to replace the wall that was removed, but the beam was not sized correctly. If it is sagging I think that is what you should assume, and hire an engineer who can confirm, and specify the way forward.  I'm not making this an answer because it's a guess, and there is already an answer that says " hire an engineer" which I think is all anyone could suggest.

Comment: Did you have the house professionally inspected before you bought it? If so, what did the inspector say about this?

Comment: Was it a PO that removed the wall?

Answer (score 9):

Was it sagging when you bought the house?

You need to document everything you do because you might have a case against the people you bought it from.

You need to have this checked out by a structural engineer. The solution may be as simple as adding a beam in the attic if you have access or much more involved if there are multiple floors. Either way, have it checked out by the pros.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with your local building department and see if a permit was pulled to remove the wall and by whom. If not and you can prove that a wall was removed ask them what the next step is. I have no clue as to what they can do but if it were you removing it in your home they could make you put it back.